# Finding norm of linear functional on $L^2([0,1])$

Tags: functional-analysis

The following defines a linear function on $L^2([0,1])$:
$$
  Lf = \sum_{n \in \mathbb Z} \frac{e^{in}}{2^{|n|}} \widehat f(n) ,
$$
where $\widehat f(n) = \langle f, e^{2\pi inx} \rangle = \int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2\pi inx} dx$.

How would I go about checking that $L$ is bounded and finding its norm?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$|\hat f (n)| = \bigg| \int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2\pi i nx}dx \bigg| \leq ||f||_2 $$

by Holder inequality.